# Microsoft Store App not downloading / Updating apps + windows updates not downloading

Tags: windows, windows-update

I have two Issues 1) Microsoft Store app not downloding any new apps or update existing apps. I have tried all the solutions i find over internet (WSreset, uninstall windows store app and reinstall, Signing out from store account etc.,) But still no luck with that.

[image]

2) WIndows updates is not downloading updates. Before it used to say "some setting are managed by organization", but since i updated the group policy setting, its not showing anymore. However, its not having any effect on downloading. Its still not downloading.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out CCleaner removed some of the services and registry files thinking them as a threats.

Had to do fresh install of windows, and make sure the "windows update" service is running in services.